# Bracket and quote completion in Revolution R

Tags: r, revolution-r

Is there a way (any particular option to be selected) to enable bracket and quote completion in Revolution R? I am using Revolution R 7.0.

What I am looking for: if I type a single " or ( or { or [ then the editor should automatically convert it into "" or () or {} or []

Comment: You can use any IDE of your choice with Revolution R.  I use RStudio - this has the features you request.

Comment: I tried RStudio with Revolution R but it frequently crashes.

Comment: Have you tried to update your installation of both RStudio and Revolution R?  We frequently use both together and I *never* get a crash.

Comment: What's the typical file size or data size for your work? In my case if I try to read anything above 0.5GB in RStudio with R chosen as Revolution R, RStudio crashes but with GNU R, it is never the case and I even work with file sizes as large as 3GB